# How to get gql return type of resolver from within resolver?

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql

EDIT: Maybe a simpler question - Is there any way of accessing __typename in a resolver? like this php question https://github.com/webonyx/graphql-php/discussions/1087

I am trying to prevent manually defining the `type` arg of `fieldWasRequested` below. Can I reliably get this string from within the resolver? This would be the same as the resolvers `__typename` value. I found a way that *kinda* gets close but is ultimately too brittle.

I am using `parseResolveInfo` from `graphql-parse-resolve-info` to check if a field was requested in a resolver. In order to do this, I need to access the type name of the resolver. Currently I am manually setting this and getting the name by looking at the graphql schema file.

```
import { parseResolveInfo } from 'graphql-parse-resolve-info'

export const fieldWasRequested = (field: string, type: string, info: GraphQLResolveInfo) => {
  const parsedInfo = parseResolveInfo(info)
  const fields = parsedInfo?.fieldsByTypeName?.[type] ?? {}
  
  return field in fields
}

export const thing1: Resolvers['thing1'] = async (parent, args, ctx, info): Promise<Thing1[]> => {
  const fieldWasRequested = fieldWasRequested('field1', 'Thing1', info)
  // continued ...
}
```

I see there is `info.returnType`, which is this [GraphQLOutputType](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/main/src/type/definition.ts#L894). This is a unioin of many types, all of which seem to have a `toString` method.

Logging `info.returnType.toString()` returns `[Thing1]`. This is an array of `Thing1`. But for other resolvers it could be `Thing2`, `[Thing3!]!`, etc. It's just not feasible to parse from this. Is there a better way?

Comment: Wouldn't it be a field in the `parent` argument?

Comment: It is not. And in some cases parent is null.